Unknown values are added to iptables
New rules are being added to the iptables firewall from an unknown source. I was doing iptables -F of mangle, nat, filter and a minute later new rules appeared. I did iptables-restore and a minute later there are new rules again.
How do I find out where these rules come from and how to disable their addition?
Example of rules:
filter: -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x100/0x100 -m mark ! --mark 0x400/0x400 -m conntrack -ctstate NEW -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
nat: -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m mark ! --mark 0x400/0x400 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j ACCEPT

Try replacing /sbin/iptables or/and /usr/sbin/iptables executable with a script that logs invocations, including a process tree to see who executed it. If it doesn't help, explore auditing functionality of your system. In principle, similar thing can be done with almost any kernel interfaces using BPF, but that is wa-a-ay more complex thing to do.

It might be Kaspersky antivirus (KESL).
